# np.sum is rounding values to the nearest integer (not wanted)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sum

(some of the code has been removed, such as plotting code, that doesn't affect the issue)

As the title states, I'm having an issue with Numpy's sum function rounding to the nearest integer.

In the following code, I create the variable chisqrR using np.sum, it works as intended, giving my a value of 1.23727.... Near the bottom of the code, I have practically the exact same code where I need to find a bunch of values for 'chisqr' based on a range of input values. The three lines of interest are:

```
chisqr[i] = np.sum(((counts - fit_exp_nonlin(t, popt[0], mu[i], popt[2]))/yerr)**2)
print(((counts - fit_exp_nonlin(t, popt[0], mu[i], popt[2]))/yerr)**2)
print(chisqr[i])
```

Where the first 'print' line, without the np.sum command, gives a bunch of values (all of which are long decimals), however, once they are summed by np.sum, I always get exact integers, which is definitely not possible. For example, one array before it's summed is:

```
[ 0.2251407   0.25516322  0.90413181  1.08316468  7.40191331  0.00893473
1.94594874  0.24967999  2.58848903  1.39550592  0.06140513]
```

and the 'sum' it gives for that array is:

```
16
```

Whereas if I sum the values manually, I get

```
16.11947726
```

Again, the full code follows:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pylab

def main():
    counts = np.array([0.72, 0.74, 0.82, 0.86, 1.18, 0.84, 1.14, 0.96, 1.44, 1.64, 1.76])
    t = np.array([108.5, 99.0, 90.0, 81.0, 71.0, 58.0, 45.0, 35.5, 26.0, 13.0, 0])/10

    xx = np.array(np.linspace(-1,max(t)+max(t)*0.1,500))
    guess1 = 1.1914367
    guess2 = 0.19740375
    guess3 = 0.61534327
    guess = (guess1, guess2, guess3)
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_exp_nonlin, t, counts, guess, maxfev=1000)    
    chisqrR = (np.sum(((counts - fit_exp_nonlin(t, *popt))/yerr)**2))/(len(t)-4)
    pylab.xlim([-1,12])
    print(chisqrR)

    mu = np.array(np.linspace(popt[1] - .1,popt[1] + .1,100))
    chisqr = np.array([0] * len(mu))
    for i in range(len(mu)):
        chisqr[i] = np.sum(((counts - fit_exp_nonlin(t, popt[0], mu[i], popt[2]))/yerr)**2)
        print(((counts - fit_exp_nonlin(t, popt[0], mu[i], popt[2]))/yerr)**2)
        print(chisqr[i])

def fit_exp_nonlin(t, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*t) + c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This has been bugging me for quite a while now and i can't seem to get it figured out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can add a data type: np.sum(... , dtype=float). Might do the trick

Comment: That works! I was unaware that np.array defaults to an integer data type. Thanks!

Comment: @John - For what it's worth, numpy doesn't default to an integer datatype. Instead, it tries to infer the type of the input.  If you pass in a sequence of floats, you'll get a float array, and likewise if you pass in a sequence of ints, you'll get an int array.  (Sequences of mixed types are either upcasted (e.g. `[0, 0.0]` would become an array of floats) or converted to an object array if any of the items is not a number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Norbert van Nobelen stated in the comments, this was fixed by changing

```
chisqr = np.array([0] * len(mu))
```

to

```
chisqr = np.array([0] * len(mu), dtype='f')
```

Thank you Norbert!